# How to search for S3 object version with specified user-defined metadata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a hundreds of versions for an S3 object, each with user-defined metadata, e.g. `version`.

I want to search for the object version with e.g. a user-defined metadata `version` of `47504`.

How can I achieve this using the AWS console or AWS CLI?

I have created the following Bash script for achieving this, but it works in serial, and is quite slow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

bucket="${1:?Missing bucket}"
key="${2:?Missing key}"


while read version
do
    aws s3api head-object --bucket "${bucket}" --key "${key}" --version-id "${version}" --output json --no-cli-pager --query '{"VersionId": VersionId, "Version": Metadata.version}'
done < <(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket "${bucket}" --prefix "${key}" --query 'Versions[].VersionId' --output json --no-cli-pager | jq -r '.[]')
```